how to use one argument in R function based on `dplyr::arrange` to sort data frame with ascending or descending
The below function can use one argument to sort data frame with multiple columns and use unquoted columns as argument.
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

tidy_eval_arrange<- function(.data, var) {
  var <- enquo(var)
  .data |>
    arrange(across(!!var))
}

tidy_eval_arrange(mtcars, var = c(cyl,mpg))
#>                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
#> Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#> Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#> Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#> Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#> Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#> Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#> Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#> Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#> Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#> Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#> Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#> Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
#> Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#> Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
#> Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
#> Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#> Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#> Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
#> Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#> AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
#> Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
#> Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
#> Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#> Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#> Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2

Created on 2024-04-15 with reprex v2.1.0
But it can not support the dplyr::desc in the tidy_eval_arrange(mtcars, var = c(cyl, desc(mpg)))

tidy_eval_arrange(mtcars, var = c(cyl, desc(mpg)))
#> Error in `arrange()`:
#> ℹ In argument: `..1 = across(c(cyl, desc(mpg)))`.
#> Caused by error in `across()`:
#> ! Problem while evaluating `desc(mpg)`.
#> Caused by error in `obj_check_vector()`:
#> ! object 'mpg' not found

How to fix the function then tidy_eval_arrange(mtcars, var = c(cyl, desc(mpg))) will work.
Created on 2024-04-15 with reprex v2.1.0

You could add it using a another function argument, e.g.   .data |> arrange(across(!!var), desc(!!var_desc))

As a potential workaround you can pass the unquoted arguments using ..., e.g.
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)

tidy_eval_arrange <- function(.data, ...) {
  dots <- quos(...)
  .data |>
    arrange(!!!dots)
}

tidy_eval_arrange(mtcars, cyl, desc(mpg))
#>                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#> Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#> Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#> Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#> Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#> Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#> Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#> Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#> Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
#> Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
#> Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#> Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#> Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#> Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
#> Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#> Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#> Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
#> Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
#> Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#> AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
#> Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
#> Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#> Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#> Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
#> Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#> Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4

Created on 2024-04-15 with reprex v2.1.0

Per Mr. Mudskipper's commented, in this case you don't need the quosure/unquote part, you can just pass in the dots.
E.g.
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)

tidy_eval_arrange <- function(.data, ...) {
  .data |>
    arrange(...)
}

tidy_eval_arrange(mtcars, cyl, desc(mpg))
#>                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#> Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#> Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#> Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#> Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#> Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#> Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#> Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#> Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
#> Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
#> Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#> Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#> Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#> Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
#> Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#> Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#> Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
#> Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
#> Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#> AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
#> Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
#> Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#> Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#> Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
#> Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#> Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4

Created on 2024-09-09 with reprex v2.1.0

Thank you very much. As the function have other arguments, I just want sort arguments in one arguments

You might actually just pass the dots here, no need for the quosure stuff

arrange(mtcars, across(c(cyl, desc(mpg)))) doesn't work because across() takes a tidy selection, which down the line is a vector of integer indices. In this context desc(mpg) doesn't mean anything, and it's not clear what c(cyl, desc(mpg)) would be expected to do because c() has no special meaning in tidy selection.
It seems you're conflating the concepts of tidy selection (used in select() or across()) and data masking (used in mutate() or arrange().
Ultimately we want to simulate arrange(mtcars, cyl, desc(mpg)), we can do this with a list of quosures or a tibble (or just dots as shown in another answer).
tidy_eval_arrange1 <- function(.data, var) {
  .data |>
     arrange({{ var }})
}

tidy_eval_arrange1(mtcars, var = tibble(cyl, desc(mpg)))
#>                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#> Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#> Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#> Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#> Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#> Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#> Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#> Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#> Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
#> Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
#> Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#> Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#> Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#> Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
#> Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#> Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#> Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
#> Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
#> Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#> AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
#> Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
#> Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#> Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#> Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
#> Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#> Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4

tidy_eval_arrange2 <- function(.data, var) {
  .data |>
    arrange(!!!var)
}

tidy_eval_arrange2(mtcars, var = quos(cyl, desc(mpg)))
#>                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#> Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#> Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#> Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#> Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#> Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#> Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#> Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#> Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
#> Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
#> Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#> Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#> Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#> Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
#> Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#> Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#> Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
#> Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
#> Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#> AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
#> Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
#> Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#> Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#> Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
#> Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#> Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4

I'd go for the tibble, because I would prefer to hide low level concepts from users, and the solution also supports passing naked variable names.

The below code converts the input var to a list of expression and inject.
library(rlang)
library(tidyverse)

tidy_eval_arrange<- function(.data, var) {
  var <- enexpr(var)
  if(is_call(var)){
    var <- call_args(var)
  } else{
    var <- rlang::list2(var)
  }
  .data |>
    arrange(!!!var)
}

tidy_eval_arrange(mtcars, var = cyl) %>% head(15)
#>                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#> Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#> Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#> Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#> Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> Toyota Corona  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#> Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#> Porsche 914-2  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#> Lotus Europa   30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#> Volvo 142E     21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
#> Mazda RX4      21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Valiant        18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
tidy_eval_arrange(mtcars, var = c(cyl,desc(mpg))) %>% head(15)
#>                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#> Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#> Lotus Europa   30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#> Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#> Porsche 914-2  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#> Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#> Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#> Toyota Corona  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#> Volvo 142E     21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
#> Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Mazda RX4      21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Ferrari Dino   19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6

Created on 2024-04-15 with reprex v2.1.0

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
